# Get values from an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have this object:

```
var data = {"id": 1, "second": "abcd"};
```

These are values from a form. I am passing this to a function for verification.

If the above properties exist we can get their values with `data["id"]` and `data["second"]`, but sometimes, based on other values, the properties can be different.

How can I get values from `data` independent of property names?

Comment: This is an _Object_, not an _Array_.

Comment: First, that's not an array. Second, what you're calling the "index" is normally called the property name or key. There's no way to get the value except by the property. Though any expression can be placed inside the `[]` and its return value will be used as the property name.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

To access the properties of an object without knowing the names of those properties you can use a `for ... in` loop:

```
for(key in data) {
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var value = data[key];
        //do something with value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to check `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: Leave the `.hasOwnProperty` check out. Let's not spread the use of unnecessary guards. It's bad practice.

Comment: @CrazyTrain let me just go add to `Object.prototype` on pages where you have code xD

Comment: @PaulS.: Sure, you could do that... and I'll go delete `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` on pages where you have code. :D The only real guard against such things is to have a strict requirement for a clean environment.

Answer (score 92):

In ES2017 you can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```
Object.values(data)
```

<strike>At the time of writing support is limited (FireFox and Chrome).</strike>All major browsers except IE support this now.

In ES2015 you can use this:

```
Object.keys(data).map(k => data[k])
```

Answer (score 51):

If you want to do this in a single line, try:

```
Object.keys(a).map(function(key){return a[key]})
```

Comment: Might be useful to point out that Object.keys() was introduced in ECMA5, supported by IE9+.

Answer (score 16):

If you `$` is defined then You can iterate

```
var data={"id" : 1, "second" : "abcd"};
$.each(data, function() {
  var key = Object.keys(this)[0];
  var value = this[key];
  //do something with value;
});
```

You can access it by following way If you know the values of keys

```
data.id
```

or

```
data["id"]
```

Answer (score 5):

I am sorry that your concluding question is not that clear but you are wrong from the very first line. The variable data is an ***Object*** not an ***Array***

To access the attributes of an object is pretty easy:

```
alert(data.second);
```

But, if this does not completely answer your question, please clarify it and post back.

Thanks !

Comment: the question is without knowing the key names, your justification did not justify the asked question

Answer (score 3):

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#values) `_.values(object)`

```
_.values({"id": 1, "second": "abcd"})

[ 1, 'abcd' ]
```

`lodash` includes a whole bunch of other functions to work with arrays, objects, collections, strings, and more that you **wish** were built into JavaScript (and actually seem to slowly be making their way into the language).

Comment: should not use lodash, it will increase the size ob bundle