# Split object into 2 arrays javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've got an object like that

```
 obj =   {
    'baz':1,
    'foo':7,
    'zap':12,
    'qax':15
    }
```

I need to split it into 2 arrays

```
arr1 = ['baz', 'foo', 'zap', 'qax']
arr2 = [1, 7, 12, 15]
```

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635866/get-values-from-object-in-javascript) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268679/best-way-to-get-the-key-of-a-key-value-javascript-object) and many others.

Answer (score 14):

Here is the simplest way:-

```
var arr1 = Object.keys(obj);
var arr2 = Object.values(obj);
```

for more please go [Standard built-in objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object)

Comment: Should be noted that this method is not supported in some browsers: [Support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-values)

Answer (score 8):

The simplest & most elegant way to do this:

```
var arr1 = Object.keys(obj);
var arr2 = arr1.map(function (k) {
    return obj[k];
});
```

Comment: don't you think elegant is a matter of opinion?

Comment: @bhspencer: perhaps, but by elegant I am referring to the shortness of it.

Answer (score 4):

```
 obj =   {
    'baz':1,
    'foo':7,
    'zap':12,
    'qax':15
    }

var arr1 = [];
var arr2 = [];

for (var prop in obj) {
   arr1.push(prop);
   arr2.push(obj[prop]);
}
```

Comment: It might not work as expected, since looping order of object keys is implementation dependent

Comment: True but the index of the key and the index of the value will match in the output arrays.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way - iterate over object properties(key, value)

```
obj =   {
    'baz':1,
    'foo':7,
    'zap':12,
    'qax':15
    }

var a = [];
var b = [];
for(var i in obj){
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)){
    a.push(i);
    b.push(obj[i]);
  }
}

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: I don't think hasOwnProperty check is necessary when using an object literal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313982/should-hasownproperty-still-be-used-with-for-in-statements

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over properties and add properties to `arr1` and values to `arr2`. You can use this code to achieve that:

```
var obj = { 'baz':1, 'foo':7, 'zap':12, 'qax':15 };
var arr1 = [];
var arr2 = [];
for(var propertyName in obj) {    // loop through properties
    arr1.push(propertyName);
    arr2.push(obj[propertyName]);
}
console.log(arr1);   // prints ["baz", "foo", "zap", "qax"]
console.log(arr2);   // prints [1, 7, 12, 15]
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
var obj = { 'baz':1, 'foo':7, 'zap':12, 'qax':15 };
var arr1 = [], arr2 = [];
for(var prop in obj){
    arr1.push(prop);
    arr2.push(obj[prop]);
}
console.log( arr1 ); // === [ "baz", "foo", "zap", "qax" ]
console.log( arr2 ); // === [ 1, 7, 12, 15 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over every attribute of your object:

```
var obj =   {
  'baz':1,
  'foo':7,
  'zap':12,
  'qax':15
}
var keys = [];
var values = [];

for(var x in obj) {
  keys.push(x);
  values.push(obj[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
obj =   {
  'baz':1,
  'foo':7,
}

const [vars, vals] = Object.keys(obj).reduce(([a, b], k) => {
   a.push(k)
   b.push(options[k])
   return [a, b]
}, [[], []])

vars //-> ['bar', 'foo']
vals //-> [1, 7]
```

Requires availability of:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)` to get the Keys of obj, and for values I'm using the for loop.

JavaScript:

```
var obj =  {
    'baz':1,
    'foo':7,
    'zap':12,
    'qax':15
    }
var j=0, val=[];
    for(let x in obj) {
        (val[j++] = obj[x]);  //storing the value of obj in val
    }

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj))
console.log(val)
```

Output:

```
[ 'baz', 'foo', 'zap', 'qax' ]
[ 1, 7, 12, 15 ]
```